# How to implement code routing Connectivity Aware Routing and Greedy Perimeter Coordinator Routing

Tags: ns2, vehicle-routing

i have a task about vanet. but I didn't find the protocol code from Connectiviy Aware Routing and Greedy Perimeter Coordinator Routing. and I need that code so that I can evaluate performance the protocol

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: CAR and GPCR : No free C++ code available for ns2. ( ?Buy code? https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+Greedy+Perimeter+Coordinator+Routing ) ... Available is GPSR-hls, GPSR-KeLiu https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing (→ 300 ns2 patches.)

Comment: my question is how to know implement code GPCR and CAR for ns2